# Redirect PayPal IPN using HTTP request

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I currently own a website that uses WHMCS as a checkout solution and as many are aware WHMCS depends on PayPal Subscriptions, so I have 50+ subscriptions active linked to my old IPN URL before migrating to my new URL. However, I do have access to my old domain still and feel like the best way to redirect IPN traffic is to create a HTTP redirect for all POST data sent to the server to my new IPN.

If someone could help me with how this would work in php exactly, it would be appreciated!
Thanks!
Regards,
Ben J

Answer (score 0):

A redirect in PHP can be done by setting the `Location: xxxx` header with the `header(` function, but whether the PayPal IPN post will follow the redirect is another question

Comment: I use this service: https://ipnforwarder.com/ so then I can change the notify url when ever i want (and also can send the ipn to multiple urls)